# How to print only datatype in Python

Tags: python-3.x

The output for type(10) is int. The output for print(type(10)) is <class 'int'>.

Is there a way of printing only the datatype in Python?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need to do this?  Is there a reason in your full program that you need this?  Or is this just a curiosity?

Comment: Just curiosity @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `__name__` attribute of the class:

```
print(type(10).__name__)
```

Output:

```
int
```

Comment: also `print (str (type (number)).split ("'") [1])`